# syncdb cannot create tables all tables

Tags: django, django-models

When I run **sqlall**,I can see the SQL for all tables,but with syncdb,two tables are not created in the database.
The two tables are defined as

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    OS_CHOICE=(('Win 2003','windows 2003'),
        ('Win 2008','Windows 2008'),
        ('Win XP','Windows XP'),
        ('Win VISTA','Win VISTA'),
        ('Win 2007','Windows 2007'),
        )
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=OS_CHOICE,default='Win 2003')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s, event_id :%s" \
            % (self.windows, self.event_id)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'event'
        verbose_name_plural='events'
class Eventgroups(models.Model):
    event=models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,  %s" \
            % (self.group_name, self.event)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'eventgroup'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'
```

Can anyone please give me an insight over this?

Comment: Most of the times this happen when you already have the table in the database. Try changing something in the models and running it again. Or else get in to manage.py shell and try creating the evengroup object and see.

Comment: I deleted the database and run the sqlall and syncdb..the two tables still do not form..all the others form correctly

Comment: Might be, try changing the model and try rerun it, If you have it in installed apps and do not have a table of the same, I dont see any reason

Comment: What happens if you remove the meta of your models and run a syncdb on a new database? Or replace db_table with verbose_name